# Switch language -> NULL (just the first language)

Tags: javascript, angular

In my webpage, I have several languages

```
 FR | NL | EN | DE | ES | IT | PT
```

[STEP 1 : OK]

I am in french, if I click on each language in my console, I retrieve the name of the language :

```
1main.js:1 Click on the current language  => nl
2main.js:1 Click on the current language  => en
3main.js:1 Click on the current language  => de
4main.js:1 Click on the current language  => es
5main.js:1 Click on the current language  => it
6main.js:1 Click on the current language  => pt
```

[click on the current language - console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaXDC.png)

```
switchLanguage(lang) {
    if (lang == 'uk') {
      lang = 'en';
    }

    this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
      this.LS.setItem('LX_Current_Language', event.lang);
      console.log("Click on the language  => " + this.LS.getItem('LX_Current_Language')); 
    });
    
    this.translate.use(lang);

    this.refresh();
  }
```

[STEP 2 : OK]
I also check the switch after each click on a language

```
Previous language : null
Click on the current language  => nl
-------------------------------------
Previous language : nl
Click on the current language  => en
-------------------------------------
Previous language : en
Click on the current language  => de
-------------------------------------
Previous language : de
Click on the current language  => es
-------------------------------------
Previous language : es
Click on the current language  => it
-------------------------------------
Previous language : it
Click on the current language  => pt
```

[previously language - console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7P1s9.png)

Why in the previous language I have a `NULL` and no `FR` please ??

Because of that, I have to click 2 times on the language `EN` to display correctly the contain of the text in English, there is a language switch problem...

[bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHqi2.png)

```
Previous language : null
Click on the current language  => nl
-------------------------------------
Previous language : nl
Click on the current language  => en
-------------------------------------
```

I don't see where is the problem please?

```
export class AuthLayoutComponent implements OnInit {
  supportedLangs;

  constructor(
    public _router: Router,
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private LS: LocalStoreService,
    public _location: Location
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.supportedLangs = ['fr', 'nl', 'en', 'de', 'es', 'it', 'pt'];
  }

  switchLanguage(lang) {
    if (lang == 'uk') {
      lang = 'en';
    }

    this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
      this.LS.setItem('LX_Current_Language', event.lang);
      console.log("Click on the current language  => " + this.LS.getItem('LX_Current_Language')); 
    });
    
    console.log("Previous language : " + this.LS.getItem('LX_Current_Language'));
    this.translate.use(lang);

    this.refresh();
  }

  refresh(): void {
    this._router.navigateByUrl("/refresh", { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
      this._router.navigate([decodeURI(this._location.path())]);
    });
  }
}
```

In HTML

```
<div class="languageSelect">
   <a href="#" *ngFor="let l of supportedLangs;" (click)="switchLanguage(l); false; ">
        {{ language | uppercase}}
   </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: `this.translate.onLangChange` appears to be asynchronous. But you're not waiting for it to finish before calling `this.translate.use(lang)` and `this.refresh()`.  I have no idea how your `TranslateService` works, but I would move `this.refresh()` into the function passed to `subscribe`.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you click on any language , it run the switchLanguage method.

Whereas this.translate.onLangChange is getting the language (waiting for the observable response in the subscribe), your code gets to

```
console.log("Previous language : " + this.LS.getItem('LX_Current_Language'));
```

and this.LS.getItem('LX_Current_Language') don't get anything yet (this first time, you don't have anything in the LocalStorage yet).

The LocalStorage will have the language once the subscribe, which was waiting to the observable response, get the response and do "this.LS.**setItem**('LX_Current_Language', event.lang);"